# Anchoring Toplevel window(s) to root window, python 2.7 - windows 7

Tags: python, tkinter

I have the layout I like, however when I move the root window I would like the Toplevel windows to move with root window.  Is this possible? I also like the idea of the user being able to move one or all of the TopLevel windows from the root window if they choose.

If not possible, is there other options that might be similar?

```
from Tkinter import *
import sys

    def main():

    root = Tk()
    root.title('skyreach')
    root.geometry('1900x1000+0+0')
    root.lower()

    board = Toplevel(root)
    board.geometry('1875x200+10+30')
    board.title('Tasked')

    board1 = Toplevel(root)
    board1.geometry('1875x200+10+270')
    board1.title('Sched and Confirm')

    board2 = Toplevel(root)
    board2.geometry('1875x200+10+510')
    board2.title('Sched')

    board3 = Toplevel(root)
    board3.geometry('1875x200+10+750')
    board3.title('Completed')

    frame = Frame(root, relief = RAISED, borderwidth = 10)
    frame.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = 1)

    frame = Frame(board, relief = RAISED, borderwidth = 10)
    frame.pack(side = BOTTOM, fill = BOTH, expand = 1)

    frame = Frame(board1, relief = RAISED, borderwidth = 10)
    frame.pack(side = BOTTOM, fill = BOTH, expand = 1)

    frame = Frame(board2, relief = RAISED, borderwidth = 10)
    frame.pack(side = BOTTOM, fill = BOTH, expand = 1)

    frame = Frame(board3, relief = RAISED, borderwidth = 10)
    frame.pack(side = BOTTOM, fill = BOTH, expand = 1)

    export = Button(root, text = 'Export to CSV', width = 20)
    export.pack(side = LEFT)
    refresh = Button(root, text = 'Refresh', width = 20)
    refresh.pack(side = LEFT)
    exitbut = Button(root,  text = 'Exit', width = 20, command = sys.exit)
    exitbut.pack(side = LEFT)

    root.mainloop()

if __name__== "__main__":
main()
```

Comment: 1)I can report that the `<Configure>` event does not react to window movement on Mac OSX(it does react to resizing). 2) I cannot even see the root window, so how would I be able to move it?  3) I can already move the toplevel windows anywhere I want, so that effect is free.

Comment: I want the toplevel windows to move with the root window, which they currently do not. If the root window was visible( I probably should have resized for the example), can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows 7, the `<Configure>` event fires when the window is dragged as well as when it is resized. You can use this event to move the Toplevel window along when the root window is moved.

Example:

```
from Tkinter import *

class App():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.geometry('300x300+100+100')
        self.root.bind('<Configure>', self.root_conf)

        self.top = []

        self.top.append(Toplevel(self.root))
        self.top[0].geometry('200x200+150+150')
        self.top[0].transient(self.root)

        self.x_off = []
        self.y_off = []        

        self.x_off.append(50)
        self.y_off.append(50)
        self.top[0].bind('<Configure>', lambda e: self.top_conf(e, 0))

        self.top.append(Toplevel(self.root))
        self.top[1].geometry('200x200+450+150')
        self.top[1].transient(self.root)

        self.x_off.append(350)
        self.y_off.append(50)
        self.top[1].bind('<Configure>', lambda e: self.top_conf(e, 1))

        self.root.mainloop()

    def root_conf(self, e):
        self.top[0].geometry('{}x{}+{}+{}'.format(self.top[0].winfo_width(), self.top[0].winfo_height(), e.x+self.x_off[0], e.y+self.y_off[0]))
        self.top[1].geometry('{}x{}+{}+{}'.format(self.top[1].winfo_width(), self.top[1].winfo_height(), e.x+self.x_off[1], e.y+self.y_off[1]))

    def top_conf(self, e, num):
        self.x_off[num] = e.widget.winfo_x()-self.root.winfo_x()
        self.y_off[num] = e.widget.winfo_y()-self.root.winfo_y()       

if __name__== "__main__":
    App()
```

---

Note that, according to @7stud's comment, this doesn't work on MacOSX, since the `<Configure>` event doesn't trigger when the window is dragged.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have been able to add a second Toplevel window but have not been able to anchor that to the root window.  Could you provide a example w/ a second window?

Comment: I'll try to add another one, but I'm not on a pc with python now, so I hope it works.

Comment: definitely close, however the two windows are created but neither are anchored to the window.

Comment: Ah damn, made a mistake somewhere then. I'll take a look at it when I'm at a computer with Python again.

Comment: Sorry it took a while, but I believe it should work now.

Comment: money in the bank, thanks. what is the reason for the empty lists 'self.top = []'?

Comment: It initializes an empty list of Toplevel windows. Then you can use append to add windows to the list. You have to initialize a list before to can use append. The reason I the windows and offsets in lists is to easily switch between the two windows in the `top_conf` function, which changes the offset of a toplevel window whenever it is dragged or resized. This way you can use the same function for as many toplevel windows as you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "transient" method of of Toplevel to define the relationship of each window. I made some modification and confirmed that now if you moved the root window, all Toplevel windows are following it.

Code:
    from Tkinter import *
    import sys

```
def main():

root = Tk()
root.title('skyreach')
root.geometry('1900x1000+0+0')
root.lower()

board = Toplevel(root)
board.transient(root)
board.geometry('1875x200+10+30')
board.title('Tasked')

board1 = Toplevel(root)
board1.transient(root)
board1.geometry('1875x200+10+270')
board1.title('Sched and Confirm')

board2 = Toplevel(root)
board2.transient(root)
board2.geometry('1875x200+10+510')
board2.title('Sched')

board3 = Toplevel(root)
board3.transient(root)
board3.geometry('1875x200+10+750')
board3.title('Completed')

frame = Frame(root, relief = RAISED, borderwidth = 10)
frame.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = 1)

frame = Frame(board, relief = RAISED, borderwidth = 10)
frame.pack(side = BOTTOM, fill = BOTH, expand = 1)

frame = Frame(board1, relief = RAISED, borderwidth = 10)
frame.pack(side = BOTTOM, fill = BOTH, expand = 1)

frame = Frame(board2, relief = RAISED, borderwidth = 10)
frame.pack(side = BOTTOM, fill = BOTH, expand = 1)

frame = Frame(board3, relief = RAISED, borderwidth = 10)
frame.pack(side = BOTTOM, fill = BOTH, expand = 1)

export = Button(root, text = 'Export to CSV', width = 20)
export.pack(side = LEFT)
refresh = Button(root, text = 'Refresh', width = 20)
refresh.pack(side = LEFT)
exitbut = Button(root,  text = 'Exit', width = 20, command = sys.exit)
exitbut.pack(side = LEFT)

root.mainloop()

if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: When executing the code I still am unable to drag the root window and have the Toplevel remain within the root window.  The only difference I have noticed is the removal of the minimize and maximize from the menu bar.

Comment: S_McC, I test the code on OSX. I did notice that the "transient" behavior is different on windows with the same code. What environment are you running? This probably the slight difference of Tk module on different platform.